# better way to load sound in android game than load from res

Tags: android, audio

I wonder how's the best way to load sound files in Game?
loading from res seems so slow, and I don't want that kind of lag happen in my game. is there any other way to load sound than load it from res file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even using `AudioTrack` causes lag as the audio buffer fills up.

Maybe a game developer can pipe up here, but my general sense from working with audio in Android is that precise timing can be difficult. Maybe someday we'll get OpenAL and this might change?

Comment: so is there any different approach? should I load all the audio in the start of the game? but how to indicate that the loading is finished?

Comment: i am not really experience with this but just a suggestion: how about u have a loading activity (like loading screen when you playing flash game). In that activity you have a progress bar to determine whether all sounds are finished loaded, afterward the main activity of your game. if you dont know how tell me, i would post a example code of how to do that:)

Comment: yes please . I always wonder how to check whether the loading is finished or not yet. :)